# Why would GAE not distribute the load to the other available instances?

Tags: google-app-engine

First thing first, here is my app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs10
env: standard
instance_class: F1
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
automatic_scaling:
  min_instances: 1
  max_instances: 20
inbound_services:
  - warmup
```

I'm using Apache Benchmark for this:

```
ab -c30 -n100000 "${URL}"
```

What I notice in the GAE console is that I have 8 instances available but only 3 take on 99% of the work. The rest is serving either no request or a very small portion.

[image]

Any idea what the problem could be here?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the [“max_concurrent_requests”](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#max_concurrent_requests) element in your “app.yaml” file, as this element is the number of concurrent requests an automatic scaling instance can accept before scheduler spawns a new instance (Keep in mind that the maximum limit is 80).

Furthermore, you can also set [“max_pending_latency”](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#max_pending_latency) that specifies the maximum amount of time that App Engine should allow a request to wait in the pending queue before starting additional instances to handle requests, so that pending latency is reduced.
If you reach the limit, it will be a signal to scale up, so the number of instances will be increased.

Comment: It seems to me that I have plenty of instances available to do the work so I don't really need to spawn more in my situation. For the max pending latency, I can add that I'm running this load test over a long time : 15-30 minutes, so I would think there is plenty of time to scale up. And really it does scale up it just that the traffic doesn't get distributed properly somehow. Those extra 5 instances are just handling <1% load for 15-30 minutes, it's pretty stable that way.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the load is not evenly distributed across the running instances is normal and actually desired as long as the number of instances still processing requests is sufficient to handle the current load level with a satisfactory level of performance - this allows the other instances to be idle long enough to be automatically shutdown (due to inactivity).

This is part of the dynamic instance management logic used with automatic and basic scheduling.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188781/in-google-app-engine-only-one-instance-handling-most-of-requests/37190854#37190854

Comment: Hmm I really don't think the 3 instances that are processing 99% are keeping up with the load. With 30 concurrent requests my understanding is that each instance can process 1 request at a time (F1 -> 1 cpu). So it seems like there is plenty of work to take on by the other instances. Also this observation doesn't change if I instances the concurrent requests to 50 or 100.

Comment: Try setting concurrent requests to 1 (that's what forces your app to only process 1 request at a time, not the single cpu). Also watch your request latency/response time (which is the most visible indicator of the running instances ability to handle the load)

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right about the 1 request at a time, I should use max_concurrent_requests. I actually haven't had the issue again today somehow, I haven't redeployed so I'm not sure what changed. I will retry again and close this if I can't reproduce. Thank for you help!